# como conectarse a ip local desde exterior, desde ip publica

Tags: redes, red

monte un experimento de server / cliente, basicamente lo sugerido aqui; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110141/establish-a-p2p-connection-in-c-sharp pero tambien logrado en javascript, y hasta en arduino (lo de encender y apagar un led con el movil). En todos los casos funciona al 1º intento. en la red LOCAL.

El problema viene cuando se intenta ampliar a fuera de la local. No hay mas que enterarse de cual es la ip publica de entrada de la local, y cambiarla en las definiciones del cliente, manteniendo igual puerto. es asi, ¿no?.

Pues no hay manera, salta error por tiempo, mientras el cliente gemelo en la local sigue funcionando.
El cliente exteriror esta en un portatil, que enlace a un punto de aceso del movil. Pero  enlazado a la local funciona.

Deshabilite los wirewall de ambos extremos. Abri un puerto del router vodafone, y tampoco. ni deseperaciones como tocar UPnP, nat transversal,,, .

Ni siquiera se donde muere el msj, ¿sale del portatil?, ¿llega a las puertas de ruter?, ¿al server?

La cantidad de gente preguntando lo mismo, sin solucion clara, lleva a pensar si ¿Es posible?. ¿No era internet la opcion de conectarse todos con todos?. ¿O lo han capado "por seguridad"?, (y de paso llevarte a servidores de pago). O QUE HAGO MAL????

Comment: La redireccion de puertos es lo que necesitas hacer en tu router o punto de acceso a internet, aparte de facilitar la comunicación mediante la regla de firewall apropiada. Suponiendo que tu servidor escucha peticiones en el puerto XXX y que su IP local es 192.168.1.100, basta con redirigir en el router de Vodafone, todas las peticiones externas de XXX a la IP local del servidor. Busca en el router la configuración de `Port forwarding` o `Redireccion de puertos`

Comment: gracias @Mauricio Contreras, creo que ya lo hice, me da a elegir entre aparatos conectados, elijo Lenovo, y ya me pone su ip, la 192.168.0.10 le pongo puerto 5000, 

¿no sera el ruter del movil?, que no puedo controlar, de todas formas, el server me dice cuando entra algo, y desde donde, no dice nada,,,

Comment: Existe o existía alguna aplicación para abrir puertos en el móvil cuando lo usas como punto de acceso, aunque desconozco si realmente funciona. Es cuestión de investigar al respecto.

Comment: Si, lo han capado, pero no por seguridad si no por falta de IP. Muchos ISP están entregando IP privadas y no publicas como antes, esto empezó con el internet móvil y se ha traspasado al internet hogar. Ojo, no confundir con IP FIJA/Dinámica, que son otros conceptos, estamos hablando de IP publico/privada, es decir tu ISP no te da acceso directo a internet, te da acceso a una red que a su vez tiene acceso a internet, por lo cual existe un router que hay que configurar el cual tu no tienes acceso. Entonces lo primero sería que averiguares si tienes IP publica o privada

Comment: que raro, deje la pareja server / cliente de experimento en c# encendido y me fui. debo aclarar que abri puerto en firewall, y hurge en el router, concretamente habilite el ddns, y le meti una cuenta de NO-IP, que aun no me aclaro. 
a eso de las 20h me canta que entro un tal "palo alto noseque", parece que una web que rastrea ips segun decia su user agent. 
hace un ratito otras dos entradas, las dejo en siguiente comentario por tamaño,

Comment: _22/22:25:27 Received: dsfsd
_22/22:25:27 Sent: DSFSD (* -> MAYUS)
_23/00:29:43 
_23/00:29:43 listening connections: 192.168.0.10 port: 5000
_23/00:29:48 
_23/00:29:48 listening connections: 192.168.0.10 port: 5000
_23/00:29:48 Received: 
       (* llega algo n blanco)

_23/00:29:48 Sent: 
   (* omito x espacio)
_23/00:34:43 
_23/00:34:43 listening connections: 192.168.0.10 port: 5000
_23/00:34:43 Received: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 62.117.237.123:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive